# Add properties to entity framework query including the object itself

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Consider this query which is going to be used in a MVC controller:

```
return
    from student in Students
    where //..
    select student;
```

the result will be converted to JSON like:

```
[
    {firstName: "John", lastName="Smith"},
    ...
]
```

I want to have a query to include courses count like this:

```
[
    {firstName: "John", lastName="Smith", courseCount: "4"},
    ...
]
```

first solution is to create a query using anonymous objects like this:

```
return
    from student in Students
    join course in Customers on course.StudentId equals student.Id 
    where //..
    group by //...
    select new {student.FirstName, student.LastName, CourseCount = courseGroup.Count()};
```

But in this way I lost the whole object of student. For example if I add `Age` property to student later, I should update this query and add `student.Age` to the select part. But in the first solution, the result includes this field automatically.

I'm looking for a more robust solution to do this select, so all changes to the `Student` class propagate to the result automatically.

**Workaround:**
This would be a solution, but it changes the JSON format and sounds a little tricky. I'm looking for a better solution. (Maybe with dynamic objects!)

```
select new { Student = student, CourseCount = courseGroup.Count()};
```

---

**EDIT:**
The desired solution is would be something like this:

```
select new Student(student){CourseCount = courseGroup.Count()}
```

Adding CourseCount in a dynamic way!

Comment: Your last snippet is not `dynamic` but it looks like the solution.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: But it changes the resulting JSON. I want the JSON to remain flat as before. Something like `select new Student(student){CourseCount = courseGroup.Count()}`. Adding `CourseCount` filed in a dynamic way!

Answer (score -1):

You could do a left join on the courses which would give you the results that you want.

[code]
return
    from student in Students
    join course in Customers on course.StudentId equals student.Id

into courseGroup
from course in courseGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

```
where //..
select new {student.FirstName, student.LastName, CourseCount = courseGroup.Count()};
```

[code]

If you do a GroupBy it will cancel out the student class and you would then have to do something like... courseGroup.StudentFirstName ... Depending on what your GroupBy looks like.

Comment: The problem is not about how to group by, The problem is that I don't want to use `student.FristName, student.LastName` explicitly to make the query more robust to changes.